# currrent time showing always utc while utc+2 zone is setting

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci

i want to add the timestamp to container logs. i did in my build stage but im gotting always the timestamp UTC and not UTC+2(paris local time):

```
stage: build
 script:
- docker info
- docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_BUILD_TOKEN $CI_REGISTRY
- echo "ETL_IMAGE = \""$CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG"\"" > version.py
- docker build --pull --tag $CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG .
- export current_date=$(TZ="Europe/Paris" date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
- echo $current_date
- docker push $CI_IMAGE_COMMIT_TAG
```

Please who can help me??
[print_current°date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bh24Y.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the timestamps you get when you add the `-t` option to `docker logs` or are you talking about timestamps generated by the program you run in your container?

Comment: i mean in the logs of the job in gitlab-ci

Comment: @HansKilian please look at the added photo in my original post. Thank you

Comment: What image are you using (it might be missing the `tzdata` package)? Also, you have a colon in front of `Europe` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @HansKilian this image: FROM rappdw/docker-java-python:openjdk1.8.0_171-python3.6.6

Comment: When I run that image and your commands (without the colon in front of 'Europe') it prints out the time in Paris local time. I think your problem comes from the colon (':').

Comment: i see why! because my container is in utc . how should i do to change the zone. ? please??

Comment: When you run the commands but with `export current_date=$(TZ="Europe/Paris" date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")` doesn't your `echo` then print the time in Paris local time?

Comment: no it gives me utc time :'( @HansKilian

Comment: i added my entire code maybe it should help please have a look @HansKilian

Comment: @HansKilianso you see something wrong?

Comment: Do you have shell access on the gitlab machine? Can you check if `tzdata` is installed? There should be a /usr/share/zoneinfo directory.

Comment: yes there is /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that maybe Gitlab runs each script command in a new shell so you can't set an environment variable and pass it to a later command. Can you try to combine the two commands to one as `export current_date=$(TZ="Europe/Paris" date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S") && echo $current_date`

Comment: it can be related to that  the container is in utc? no?

Comment: @HansKilian **export current_date=$(TZ="Europe/Paris" date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S") && echo $current_date** gives me utc time

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the container. Your export and echo script commands are running in Gitlab AFAIK. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Yes !! its really weird ! don't know what to do ? oh :/ @HansKilian

Comment: @HansKilian as i said im using this image rappdw/docker-java-python:openjdk1.8.0_171-python3.6.6 and after reasearch, it does not contain tzdata.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set the `TZ` environment variable on the container level?

```yaml
your_job:
  variables:
    TZ: Europe/Paris
  script:
    - export current_date=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
    - echo $current_date
```

Comment: it is always in utc. look at the added photo in my original post. Thank you